# Multicast routing , why do we need pimreg interface?

Tags: linux-kernel, routes, multicast

I'm using pimd in my project. https://github.com/troglobit/pimd.
PIM daemon creates a 'pimreg' virtual interface. 
Multicast routing works perfectly. but I'm curious why do we need 'pimreg' interface at all.

The code which handles virtual interface creation in kernel is:

```
static struct net_device *ipmr_reg_vif(struct net *net, struct mr_table *mrt)
{
    struct net_device *dev;
    struct in_device *in_dev;
    char name[IFNAMSIZ];

    if (mrt->id == RT_TABLE_DEFAULT)
        sprintf(name, "pimreg");
    else
        sprintf(name, "pimreg%u", mrt->id);

    dev = alloc_netdev(0, name, reg_vif_setup);

    if (dev == NULL)
        return NULL;

    dev_net_set(dev, net);

    if (register_netdevice(dev)) {
        free_netdev(dev);
        return NULL;
    }
    dev->iflink = 0;

    rcu_read_lock();
    in_dev = __in_dev_get_rcu(dev);
    if (!in_dev) {
        rcu_read_unlock();
        goto failure;
    }

    ipv4_devconf_setall(in_dev);
    IPV4_DEVCONF(in_dev->cnf, RP_FILTER) = 0;
    rcu_read_unlock();

    if (dev_open(dev))
        goto failure;

    dev_hold(dev);

    return dev;

failure:
    /* allow the register to be completed before unregistering. */
    rtnl_unlock();
    rtnl_lock();

    unregister_netdevice(dev);
    return NULL;
}
```

and I see most of the time tx and rx packets are 0.

```
ifconfig pimreg

pimreg: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 1472
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 0  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

On further debugging I found all PIM packets are lifted from kernel to userspace through pim_socket.
So why do we need pimreg virtual interface on first place?
What is the linux kernel pimd design objective for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pimreg` interface is created by the kernel when `pimd` opens
the multicast routing socket and performs its `ioctl` magic.

The interface is used for register tunnels, i.e. when tunneling
multicast stream(s) from the rendez-vous point (RP) to the designated
router (DR).

More information about this is available in [RFC4601](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4601).